# Interim work when pushing a box on a frictionless surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

When a box is being pushed on a frictionless 2D surface back along a path back to its starting point, the total work being done is zero.

However when we examine the box at a point along this path, I presume that some work has been done, as the box was displaced.

- What is that work that was done at an interim path point - can we calculate it in principle?
- How to make sense of what happens when the box is being pushed back to origin - why the work is negative? After all it's still being pushed, so we're doing work. Is it because of arbitrary choice of coordinates?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the work is zero along the closed path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be confusing work by a force and the net work.

I will remind you that the net work is defined as the sum of all work, and equals the change in kinetic energy of the object.

$$W_{\rm net}\equiv \sum_i W_i = \Delta {\rm KE} = \dfrac1 2 mv_f^2-\dfrac1 2 mv_i^2\tag1$$

On the other hand, the work by a certain force $\vec F_i$ on the object over some path $C:\vec r (t)$ is defined as
$$W_{\mathrm{by}\vec F_i}\equiv \int_C \vec F\cdot d\vec r \tag 2$$
If we assume that the force is constant, then Eq. (2) simplifies to the following familiar equation:$$W_i = \vec F_i\cdot \Delta\vec r=F_i\Delta r\cos\theta$$

> What is that work that was done at an interim path point - can we calculate it in principle?

Yes, by equation (2) you can calculate the work done by a force over a path.

> How to make sense of what happens when the box is being pushed back to origin - why the work is negative?

The net work along a closed path (i.e. you start and end at the same point) **is not necessarily zero**.

If it's just you pushing the box (i.e. the force you apply = the net force), then in that case, the net work = the work you do = change in kinetic energy:
$$W_\mathrm{net} = W_\mathrm{by \; you}=\Delta \mathrm{KE}$$

If the box starts off with speed $v$, but when it's back at its initial position, it has a speed *not* equal to $v$, then the net work was **not** zero (since there is a change in kinetic energy, because the speed of the box is different at the start and end).

However, what you are probably referring to, is: the box starting from rest, moving, then finishing at the same spot at rest (i.e. starts from rest, moves, finishes at rest). In that case, what happens is you apply some your force to speed the block up and move it, hence giving it some speed. However, in order to slow the box down (so it finishes at rest), you must apply a force *opposite* to the path the block takes to slow it down. Forces acting against the object's path (i.e. slowing it down) result in negative work. Therefore, the same work you do to speed the box up, you will have to do that (negative) same amount of work to slow it down. So, the total work you do is zero.

> After all it's still being pushed, so we're doing work. Is it because of arbitrary choice of coordinates?

Yes it's being pushed, and yes you're doing work. Assuming you provide the net force, if **you** do zero work it's either because (i) you never speed the object up, or (ii) because you speed the object up and then you slow it down such that it starts and finishes with the same speed.

Coordinate systems have nothing to do with it. You can do the math in spherical or cartesian or any type of coordinates, if the forces and path are the same, the work won't change.

I'd also recommend reading the following: [Net Work Done When Lifting an Object at a constant speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/594580/net-work-done-when-lifting-an-object-at-a-constant-speed/594631#594631). It should clear up your doubts.

Comment: "... because you speed the object up and then you slow it down such that it starts and finishes with the same speed" - I am not referring to system of coordinates, but to the reference frame. So in this case, why slowing the box down is "negative" work? You have to apply force.

Comment: For simplicity, I will assume a constant force, such that the following equation: $W=\vec F\cdot \Delta \vec r=F\Delta r \cos\theta$ is valid. If the $\vec F$ vector and the $\Delta \vec r$ vector are both parallel (pointing in the same direction), then the angle between them is zero, so $\cos 0 =1$ so the work is positive (since both $F$ and $\Delta r$ must be positive, as they are magnitudes). However, if the $\Delta \vec r$ vector points opposite to $\vec F$ vector (i.e. force opposes motion), then the angle between the vectors is 180, and since $\cos180=-1$, so the work is negative.

Comment: The reference frame would have to be non inertial, but yes, it is possible to make such a choice of reference frame.